# How can I bind ng-repeat to the previously clicked ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to use an ng-repeat that only references the previously clicked ng-click function.

What I'm trying to create is a demo app with dynamic dummy content.

The concept is:

Click a link from a content set and display the json data (headlines) just pertaining to that link.

I've noted the problematic repeater in the html

demo: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/C7MlbHDawSdASHl1aLBB?p=preview)

I'm kinda new to angular so if there is an easier method to doing this, any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. The demo can be a useful addition, but a question must be self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second block contains two nested ng-repeats: one that iterates over the contentSets, and one that iterate over the headlines of the current content. You want a single ng-repeat, which iterates over the content that has been clicked in the top block. And this clicked content is stored in the scope variable `useContent` by your `setContent()` function (called by the ng-click). So that's what you must iterate over:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" >
    <li ng-repeat="headline in useContent.headlines">
        {{headline.headline}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

You got it right for the `<h1>`, which displayed the appropriate title, BTW.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/guAapCDRzPI1i51OfRAS?p=preview

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Do you think this method is standard to use when binding across different pages/routes?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: No worries, I think I have it figured out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Uyl4AwOoXkHD21toHZT?p=preview)

You only need to put ng-show on the ul element, and only show it when `content == useContent`

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="content in contentSets" ng-show="content == useContent">
    <li ng-repeat="headline in content.headlines">
      <a href="#">{{headline.headline}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: ng-if is better because it creates the code when it's necessary. No need of shady code :)

Comment: Thanks guys, these are also very helpful tips